# CSS files seems imported twice with Next.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm in the process of migrating a little project for myself from React.JS to Next.JS and it seems that css files are processed twice with different names.
I'm a little bit of a noob in web development so i don't really understand why it is happening and if it's the result of some of the problems i'm encountering at the moment.

Here is the architecture of my project:
[Project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVt03.jpg)

And here's what i get in the devtool:
[devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXIjr.jpg)

Note that Header and Footer components are both imported in the root layout so they show up on every pages, also, header's CSS is in module and footer's css is not is because i tried converting in modules to see if it change the result but it doesn't.

TLDR: Tried to add css to footer and header components but they show up twice and doesn't look like what they were before migrating from ReactJS to NextJS

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed on next 14.1.1-canary.43.

Check PR here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/61198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an error beyond your control. This situation is observed in some versions of Next.js. Solution: Change the version of Next.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think it was indeed ! Problem solved by itself, i'm guessing it's an issue with nextjs builder or compiler